# ApplicationScoped Bean or Singleton for Database representation?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb

I have information stored in a database (actually a content repository but this shouldn't matter) which should be presented to all users. Currently I have a Singleton Bean which fetches this information and stores it in a variable. This fetch operation is called every time an update happen on the database so that the variable, representing the database content, is always up to date. Also this variable is used by jsf managed beans to display the information. What I wanted to avoid with this approach is that a new database connection has to be opened for every read-only request. Does this approach make sense or should I use an application scoped managed bean instead? I would then have to call the update method of the managed bean from within an EJB. Is there something wrong with doing this?

Comment: The way how the question is put hints that you're using plain vanilla JDBC instead of JPA+JTA+connectionpool. Is this true?

Comment: Ok so the content repository seems to be of interest after all. I'm using the jcr api as a resource adapter and jackrabbit as the implemention, for receiving the information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to persist information across all sessions of a given web application in JSF then it is best to use Application Scoped and not use a static singleton.

Here are a few reasons why:

1. Static fields are based on the class loaded in a specific VM.  If your application were to be load balanced or clustered then there is no chance that other application server nodes will have access to the information stored on another servers VM.
2. ApplicationScoped beans can be serializable, meaning that certain web and application containers have the ability to persist these scoped beans to disk in the event of a server restart.  This is dependent on the functionality of your given server however.
3. Certain application servers have good clustering support as well as sticky sessions and global cluser wide application scope.  This will allow sessions to be routed to another server successfully if the current sessions server would unexpectedly go down.  Also ApplicationScoped beans would be public and accessible everywhere throughout your application regardless of which node is serving a given request.  Again, this is highly dependent on the application containers features and configuration.
4. Static fields would not only be accessible to every request on a given application's VM, it will be available to EVERY request on EVERY application running on a given VM.  If the application server or web container is running multiple web application and they both utilize the same classes then they could be inadvertently sharing information or clashing with each other.  Not a good design choice.

For more information see below:

https://blogs.oracle.com/groundside/entry/application_scope_v_s_static

Comment: thank you for this input. In my case I don't want to persist data across all sessions. I only want to PRESENT the same data across all request. So I'm looking for the best way to show the database content to every user without opening a direct database connection for every user...

Comment: @user1644061 It is the same principle though... You would be persisting an Application Scoped bean for all requests and this bean happens to have a reference to a datasource connection.  Just having a connection though is inherently unsafe, you are better having a reference to a connection factory that will create a new connection for you if something were to happen and the current connection ends up closed.

Comment: ok thank you very much I'll use an application scoped bean then. From your answer I guess there's nothing wrong with calling the bean from within an EJB? And : Since an application scoped bean is only instantiated once is there something wrong with having methods in it ? For example a method which allows a user to download a file in a saveas dialog?

Comment: @user1644061 I believe that the ApplicationScoped bean is instantiated the moment it is injected into a newly created Managed Property of another bean and only if it doesn't already exist.  Unless you are using a seperate DI container like CDI or Spring, it will also need to be serializable, because it essentially serializes the applicationscoped bean in the applications ServletContext in memory or on temp disk space.  It will live as long as the server is running, or until the application is undeployed, or until manually removed or destroyed from ServletContext.